# html input attribute values in uppercase

Tags: html

I have the below given

with lowercase name and id values

```
<input type="text" name="abc" id ="abc">
```

with uppercase name and id values

```
<input type="text" name="ABC" id ="ABC">
```

I have seen only lowercase name and id values. Can we use uppercase also? Is there a benefit using lowercase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What values are acceptable for a given attribute depend on the specific attribute.

Name and Id attributes can both include upper and lower case characters, and both are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

> Case insensitivity in **tag names** and **attribute names**
>
> **Tag names** for HTML elements may be written with any mix of lowercase
>   and uppercase letters that are a case-insensitive match for the names
>   of the elements given in the HTML elements section of this document;
>   that is, tag names are case-insensitive.
>
> **Attribute names** for HTML elements may be written with any mix of
>   lowercase and uppercase letters that are a case-insensitive match for
>   the names of the attributes given in the HTML elements section of this
>   document; that is, attribute names are case-insensitive.

And for Values:

> Some **attribute values** are case insensitive, while other attribute
>   values—most notably the attributes id and class—are case sensitive. As
>   these attributes are case sensitive in HTML, ID selectors and class
>   selectors must always match the case of the id and class attribute
>   values in the document. To find out which attribute values are case
>   sensitive and which aren’t, consult the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.1).

Comment: The question is asking about attribute *values* not tag or attribute *names*.

Comment: No, values can be case sensitive. While upper and lower case characters are often allowed, they will often have different effects. You can't switch case freely without other things that use the value compensating.

Comment: When quoting other documents, always state your source(s).

Answer (score 0):

yes ... they can be uppercase or lowercase ...
for example consider the __VIEWSTATE  that is usually used in hidden inputs ( ASP.Net Websites ) 
these are just names ... so there is no benefit if you use uppercase or lowercase...